Запятые между однородными дополнениями
Есть такое предложение: "И взял масла, и молока, и телёнка приготовленного, и поставил перед ними". Здесь, как видим, идёт перечисление, три однородных дополнения. Запятые, согласно правилам, расставлены верно. Такая расстановка запятых приравнивает все три дополнения между собой.
Однако возможен акцент на смысловое единство масла и молока (которые в определённом смысле противопоставляются телёнку), тогда, по идее, здесь два дополнения: 1) масло и молоко; 2) телёнок; следовательно, запятые вообще не нужны: "взял масла и молока и телёнка приготовленного". Хотя интонационно в таком случае было бы правильнее поставить запятую перед вторым союзом "и": "взял масла и молока, и телёнка приготовленного" (телёнок в данном случае выделяется как некий оборот).
Как считаете, какие варианты допустимы и какой более верный в случае со смысловым единством первых двух дополнений?

Правильная запись в оригинале:
Ефрем Сирин, прп. (†373)  
Ст. 7-8 И побежал Авраам к стаду, и взял теленка нежного и 
хорошего, и дал отроку, и тот поспешил приготовить его. И 
взял масла и молока и теленка приготовленного, и поставил 
перед ними, а сам стоял подле них под деревом. И они ели.

И взял масла и молока и теленка приготовленного, и поставил перед ними.
Пояснение

Повторяющийся союз И...И соединяет однородные  сказуемые (и взял, и поставил).

Три дополнения оформлены по схеме 2 + 1, то есть первый союз И соединяет два первых дополнения (масла и молока)  а второй союз присоединяет к ним третье дополнение (и теленка приготовленного).


Розенталь § 13. Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами
8. Если два однородных члена предложения, 
соединенные союзом и, образуют тесно связанную по 
смыслу пару, соединенную союзом и с третьим 
однородным членом, запятая не ставится:  Пройти 
огонь и воду и медные трубы (Погов.); 


Спасибо. Насчёт оригинала: у синодального перевода имеются серьёзные проблемы с пунктуацией. Во-первых, она следует нормам XIX века, а во-вторых, содержит очень много явных ошибок. Я рассмотрел этот стих в разных переводах (в древнееврейском оригинале запятых не было). Пунктуационные указания на то, что масло и молоко образуют смысловое единство, нашлись в синодальной редакции 1902 г. (без запятых), 1948 г. (запятая перед телёнком) и в переводе Глухарёва (аналогично), то есть в 3-х случаях из более чем 15. Зато в малорусских и белорусских переводах эта формула доминирует (7 из 8).

Вот потому я и задался этим вопросом: не совсем очевидно, то ли кто-то не совсем грамотно запятые расставляет, то ли это действительно разные смысловые вариации. Кстати, а возможен ли вообще вариант с одной запятой, как, например, "неужели я и твоя мать, и твои братья придем поклониться тебе до земли?" (Быт.37:10)?

Мне оригинал потребовался, чтобы определить повторяющийся союз И..И для сказуемых по контексту. Остальное решено строго по правилам. Приведенное оформление тоже возможно как вариант,  но структура предложения недостаточно ясна из-за скопления союзов И.

Правильно: неужели я, и твоя мать, и твои братья придем поклониться тебе до земли?  // Одну запятую нельзя ставить.

Вот, а в тексте так и стоит.  Хотя во фрагменте предшествующего стиха "вот, солнце и луна(,) и одиннадцать звёзд поклоняются мне" одна запятая уже не смотрелась бы так дико, как мне кажется (но, следуя логике масла-молока и избегая двусмысленности, её лучше не ставить).

Здесь нужно так:"Вот солнце. и луна, и одиннадцать звёзд поклоняются мне". Перечислительная интонация, совсем без запятых хуже читается. А после указательной частицы "вот" запятую практически не ставят.

Ну, кто как. В русской Библии "вот" приобретает оттенок вводного слова и пишется с запятой более 1000 раз, а как без неё - менее 700.

Интересно! Тогда пусть это будет специфика текста. А как тогда различать варианты? //  В правилах так. У Фрамполь нет вводности для частиц ВОТ, И ВОТ. В Грамоте нашелся ответ № 300463
Добрый день! Будет ли правильно обособить: Вот(,)послушайте. Далее следует небольшая история.
ответ
Возможны оба варианта: с запятой и без запятой.  // Ссылка на  словарь Фрамполь file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/104498_edb50bec111d553f5056bb5b92bc0db2.pdf

Конечно, Срамота.ру - так себе авторитет в вопросах правописания, но авторы синодального перевода и ихний стиль если даже и не предъявляют образец идеального языка, то как минимум заслуживают внимания. В тексте Библии, по-моему, разница довольно заметна по смыслу, например: "вот человек, который любит есть и пить вино, друг мытарям и грешникам" и "вот, ученики Твои делают, чего не должно делать в субботу".  В первом случае - прямое указание на объект ("Это человек, который..."); во втором случае можно было бы сказать: "Обрати внимание (смотри; представь...), ученики Твои...".
